# R Example - ddply, ave, and merge

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I have written a code. It would be great if you guys can suggest better way of doing the stuff I am trying to do. The dt is given as follows:

```
   SIC FYEAR AU       AT
1    1  2003  6  212.748
2    1  2003  5 3987.884
3    1  2003  4  100.835
4    1  2003  4 1706.719
5    1  2003  5    9.159
6    1  2003  7   60.069
7    1  2003  5  100.696
8    1  2003  4  113.865
9    1  2003  6  431.552
10   1  2003  7  309.109 ...
```

My job is to create a new column for a given SIC, and FYEAR, the AU which has highest percentage AT and the difference between highest AT and second highest AT will get a value 1, otherwise 0. Here, is my attempt to do the stuff mentioned.

```
a <- ddply(dt,.(SIC,FYEAR),function(x){ddply(x,.(AU),function(x) sum(x$AT))});

   SIC FYEAR AU        V1
1    1  2003  4  3412.619
2    1  2003  5 13626.241
3    1  2003  6   644.300
4    1  2003  7  1478.633
5    1  2003  9     0.003
6    1  2004  4  3976.242
7    1  2004  5  9383.516
8    1  2004  6   457.023
9    1  2004  7   456.167
10   1  2004  9   238.282
```

where V1 represnts the sum AT for all the rows for a given AU for a given SIC and FYEAR. Next I do :

```
a$V1 <- ave(a$V1, a$SIC, a$FYEAR, FUN = function(x) x/sum(x));

   SIC FYEAR AU           V1
1    1  2003  4 1.780949e-01
2    1  2003  5 7.111150e-01
3    1  2003  6 3.362420e-02
4    1  2003  7 7.716568e-02
5    1  2003  9 1.565615e-07
6    1  2004  4 2.740114e-01
7    1  2004  5 6.466382e-01
8    1  2004  6 3.149444e-02
9    1  2004  7 3.143545e-02
10   1  2004  9 1.642052e-02
```

The column V1 now represents the percentage value for each AU for AT contribution for a given SIC, and FYEAR. Next,

```
a$V2 <- ave(a$V1, a$SIC, a$FYEAR, FUN = function(x) {t<-((sort(x, TRUE))[2]); 
                                                    ifelse((x-t)> 0.1,1,0)});

   SIC FYEAR AU           V1 V2
1    1  2003  4 1.780949e-01  0
2    1  2003  5 7.111150e-01  1
3    1  2003  6 3.362420e-02  0
4    1  2003  7 7.716568e-02  0
5    1  2003  9 1.565615e-07  0
6    1  2004  4 2.740114e-01  0
7    1  2004  5 6.466382e-01  1
8    1  2004  6 3.149444e-02  0
9    1  2004  7 3.143545e-02  0
10   1  2004  9 1.642052e-02  0
```

The AU for a given SIC, and FYEAR, which has highest percentage contribution to AT, and f the difference is greater than 10%, the that AU gets 1 else gets 0.

Then I merge the result with original data dt.

```
dt <- merge(dt,a,key=c("SIC","FYEAR","AU"));

   SIC FYEAR AU       AT           V1 V2
1    1  2003  4 1706.719 1.780949e-01  0
2    1  2003  4  100.835 1.780949e-01  0
3    1  2003  4  113.865 1.780949e-01  0
4    1  2003  4 1491.200 1.780949e-01  0
5    1  2003  5 3987.884 7.111150e-01  1
6    1  2003  5  100.696 7.111150e-01  1
7    1  2003  5   67.502 7.111150e-01  1
8    1  2003  5 9461.000 7.111150e-01  1
9    1  2003  5    9.159 7.111150e-01  1
10   1  2003  6  212.748 3.362420e-02  0
```

What I did is very cumbersome. Is there a better way to do the same stuff? Thanks.

Comment: you're ok using packages, are unhappy with cumbersome syntax and when presented with a better option you don't like it because it uses a package? wat? @Arun imo you should undelete your answer - if OP wants to go back to `data.frame` afterwards for whatever reason I don't see what's stopping them.

Comment: I am a R novice. And I want to master basic R, and hence do not want to use data table for my purposes even though I have a data size of more than 70k rows with 40 columns. I believe that data table would be faster for my purposes, but I would stick to data frame to get expertise at R.

Comment: You do realize that `ddply` is not basic R, right? Whatever, to each their own, just pointing out that your logic makes no sense.

Comment: I must say that I really tried to understand what you mean. your example is incomplete in the sense that I don't see all the data and can't verify my own code. I does seem, however, that your problem, once properly defined, can be solved in basic R fairly simply. but I can't be sure and can't tell you how before I understand better your goal, see a fuller example, and understand, at least a bit, the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if the deleted answer was the same as this, but you can effectively do it in a couple of lines.

```
# Simulate data
set.seed(1)
n<-1000
dt<-data.frame(SIC=sample(1:10,n,replace=TRUE),FYEAR=sample(2003:2007,n,replace=TRUE),
AU=sample(1:7,n,replace=TRUE),AT=abs(rnorm(n)))

# Cacluate proportion.
dt$prop<-ave(dt$AT,dt$SIC,dt$FYEAR,FUN=prop.table)
# Find AU with max proportion.
dt$au.with.max.prop<-
  ave(dt,dt$SIC,dt$FYEAR,FUN=function(x)x$AU[x$prop==max(x$prop)])[,1]
```

It is all in base, and avoids `merge` so it won't be that slow.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(your_data_frame)
setkey(DT, SIC, FYEAR, AU)
DT[setkey(DT[, sum(AT), by=key(DT)][, V1 := V1/sum(V1), 
          by=list(SIC, FYEAR)])[, V2 := (V1 - V1[.N-1] > 0.1) * 1, 
          by=list(SIC, FYEAR)]]
```

The part `DT[, sum(AT), by=key(DT)][, V1 := V1/sum(V1), by=list(SIC, FYEAR)]` first sums `AT` by all three columns and then replaces V1 by V1/sum(V1) by columns `SIC, FYEAR` by reference. The `setkey` wrapping this code orders all four columns. Therefore, the last but one value will always be the second highest value (under the condition that there are no duplicated values). Using this, we can create `V2` as: `[, V2 := (V1 - V1[.N-1] > 0.1) * 1, by=list(SIC, FYEAR)]]` by reference. Once we've this, we can perform a `join` by using `DT[.]`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am looking for a solution where data frame is not converted to data table. Interested in pure data frame solution. Thanks.